WordPress Menu is expecting wp post element
Trying to add a Page Element to a Menu results that WordPress is hanging - in the debug.log I see an error similar like it is expecting a WP_Post Element (which makes no sense in this case here). How is it possible to restrict WordPress to only accept wp_post elements as Menu Elements? Or asked the other way around - where do I have to dig to disable this?
Any help greatly appreciated.
[03-Nov-2024 10:09:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: 
Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local::on_save_post(): Argument #2 ($post) 
must be of type WP_Post, null given, called in 
/home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php 
on line 326 and defined in 
/home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/template-library/sources/local.php:1112 

Stack trace:
#0 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(326): 
   Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local->on_save_post()
#1 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): 
   WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): 
   WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/post.php(4891): 
   do_action()
#4 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/nav-menu.php(541): 
   wp_insert_post()
#5 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php(1184): 
   wp_update_nav_menu_item()
#6 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php(1567): 
   wp_save_nav_menu_items()
#7 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): 
   wp_ajax_add_menu_item()
#8 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): 
   WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#9 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): 
   WP_Hook->do_action()
#10 /home/u628460773/domains/abcacademy.com/public_html/abcdev/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(192): 
    do_action()
#11 {main}


Is Elementor up to date? This appears to be an issue with the plugin and not the theme. When you say Trying to add a Page Element to a Menu where are you doing this? Also, why would you say which makes no sense in this case here for the WP_Post Element error?

Elementor is up-to-date @disinfor, Elementore Pro is not (Client uses...sigh.. a nulled license obviously). I am going to APPEARANCE / Menu / Add Menu Items. "Add Menu Items" differentiates between Pages and Posts.

Something also strange happening when I try to move all Elementor Templates into Bin - I get immediately a Critical WP Error, shortly after a "Cannot move to Bin Error" but in the debug log I do not see anything related to it. Weird.

You'll need to update Elementor Pro -  the client will need to update their license. If Elementor (free) is up to date, but Pro is not, you are going to get a ton of errors.

We did update Elementor Pro to the latest (bought the license) - but the errors did not disappear.

Can you add a list of active plugins to your question?

You need to customize how WordPress handles menu items.
Follow these steps below to make it so it only accepts wp_post:

Hide Unwanted Menu Item Types with Custom CSS or JavaScript
You can hide the options in the menu interface with CSS or JavaScript by adding this to your theme’s functions.php file or a custom plugin. This method hides the elements visually but doesn’t completely remove their functionality.

Filter the Available Menu Items
You can use the wp_nav_menu_items filter to limit the items that appear in the navigation menu. Here’s an example of how to add only posts as options for menu items:
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', function($items) {
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    // Check if the menu item is not a post
    if ($item->object !== 'post') {
        unset($items[$key]); // Remove the item from the menu
    }
}
return $items;

});


This filter runs when WordPress is fetching the menu items to display, so only posts appear in the front end.
3.  Customize the WordPress Admin UI with JavaScript

You can use JavaScript in the WordPress admin to hide the options for other types of menu items. Add this code to the functions.php file:
function restrict_menu_items() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Hide pages, custom links, categories, etc.
        $('#posttype-page, #custom, #category').hide();
    });
</script>
<?php

}
add_action('admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'restrict_menu_items');

Use wp_get_nav_menu_items to Restrict Only to Posts
Modify the wp_get_nav_menu_items filter to restrict the menu query to only include post types:
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'restrict_menu_to_posts', 10, 3);
function restrict_menu_to_posts($items, $menu, $



I don't think they are trying to limit the menu to wp_post. They are wondering why they got that error when adding a page element - probably not realizing that the page post type is part of WP_Post.

@disinfor Thats right.
